# Changing hover over information in thumbnail view in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, picture-library

We have a picture library that has employee photos shown in a thumbnail view.  It shows the picture and the employee name which is the file name (John Doe.jpg).  When you click on the picture it contains further employee details like Job Title, Department, Phone Number, Email Address, etc…  We recently upgraded to SharePoint 2013 and now the employee photos show in thumbnail view but instead of showing the employee name, it shows their Job Title instead.  When I hover over the photo it shows the file details as well like file extension, image dimensions, file size.  Is there an easy way to change the hover over information?  I've tried modifying the view but it doesn't seem to be changing anything.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ryan, I don't follow you (and I would put this question under comments to your posting, but the site says I'm not allowed...). No matter what I do, the info that's displayed when I hover over a thumbnail is the name of the file, the format of the file, the size of the picture and the size of the file. I can't get that to change no matter what I do.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the quick fix to my issue.  The hover over in thumbnail view is using the “Title” field.  I created a custom view that listed the Name field (which contains the employee’s name) and the Title field (which is currently blank).  Switched to Quick Edit and selected a group of Names and copied them to the Title column.  Then went back to my thumbnail view and the hover over now contains the employee names.